# vue.js +axiosでデータベースの値を$dataに格納したい

Tags: python, javascript, django, vue.js, axios

Djangoでwebアプリを作成しており、template内でVue.jsを使用しています。
axiosを使ってデータベースにアクセスしており、データの受け渡し自体は上手くいっているようなのですが、.then()の中からthis.$dataにアクセスしようとすると何故かundifinedになってしまいます。

**myscript.js**

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#article',
    delimiters: ['[[ ', ']]'],
    data: {
        gooded_articles: [],
    },
    created: function () {

        //(1)
        console.log(this.gooded_articles);

        axios.get('/snsapp/gooded_articles/')
            .then(function (response) {

                //(2)
                console.log(this.gooded_articles);

                var article_ids = response.data.article_ids;

                //(3)
                console.log(article_ids);

                for (var i = 0; i < article_ids.length; i++) {
                    gooded_articles.push(article_ids[i]);
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
    },
});
```

**urls.py**

```python
urlpatterns = [
    path('gooded_articles/', views.GoodedArticles.as_view(), name='gooded_articles'),
]
```

**views.py**

```python
class GoodedArticles(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.SessionAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        good_instances = Good.objects.filter(pusher=request.user)
        article_ids = []
        for good_instance in good_instances:
            gooded_article = good_instance.article
            article_ids.append(gooded_article.id)
        data = {
            'article_ids': article_ids,
        }
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

コンソールの結果
- (1) : `[__ob__: Observer] length: 0`
- (2) : `undefined`
- (3) : `(2) [1, 3]`
- ReferenceError: gooded_articles is not defined

参考にしたコードでは.then()内からもthis.$dataにアクセスできていたので原因が分かりません。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.then()の中のthisはaxiosオブジェクトになっているようなので、.bind(this)でバインドするか、thisが変わらないようにアロー関数で書くことで解決しました。